# Installing MYSQL Developer Tools on Win 10 32 Bit

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying to install the MYSQL developer tools on an 32 Bit win 10 system but i need visual studio 2015, 2017 or 2019 but I cant install them on my 32 bit system and without I cant install the tools I need.

Would be happy for some help or suggestions.

Greeting little student.

Comment: For example the mysql workbench cant install it on the win 10 32 bit operating system...